# Issue in changing odata version in webide

Tags: odata, sapui5, web-ide

I am trying to change my OData version as V1 in my Web IDE,I tried by keeping the below code in model object in `mainfest.json`.

```
"": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel",
    "dataSource": "mainService",
    "settings": {
        "metadataUrlParams": {
            "sap-documentation": "heading"
        }
    }
}
```

when the control comes to *component.js*, `this.getModel()` gives me OData version as V1, but when I am executing this line

```
UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
```

giving me the error as

```
 Uncaught TypeError: this.getOwnerComponent(...).getModel(...).metadataLoaded is not a function.
```

I am developing `SAPUI5` Master-Detail application in Web IDE. How to solve this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the difference from 1.28 to anything higher is metadataLoaded-function. SAP changed it in their Versions... bad habbit btw.

In 1.28 you need to use it without a promise:

```
oDataModel.onMetadataLoaded(function(data) {
    console.log('finished', data);
});
```

Above 1.28 you can use it with promise

```
oDataModel.metadataLoaded().then(function(data) {
   console.log('finished', data);
});
```

Comment: this is btw. why it tells you "it is not a valid function"